# LINQ Group By com múltiplos campos

Tags: c#, linq

Estou tentando retornar campos após uma junção entre coleções, mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'AnonymousType#1' because 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
var lst = from p in Produto.produtos
        join c in Produto.categorias
        on p.IdCategoria equals c.IdCategoria
        group p by new { c.IdCategoria, c.Categoria }
            into g
            orderby g.Key.Categoria
            select new { ID = g.Key.IdCategoria, CategoriaNome = g.Key.Categoria, TotalItem = g.Count() };

foreach (var categ in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Categoria: {1}, Total Item: {2}", categ.ID, categ.CategoriaNome, categ.TotalItem);
    foreach (var item in categ)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tID: {0}, Produto: {1}", item.IdProduto, item.Produto); <b>// Linha com o Erro</b>
    }
}
```

Comment: Melhorei minha resposta. Veja agora se te atende.

Answer (score 4):

Isto devolve `List<n'>`, em que `n'` é um tipo anônimo:

```
var lst = from p in Produto.produtos
        join c in Produto.categorias
        on p.IdCategoria equals c.IdCategoria
        group p by new { c.IdCategoria, c.Categoria }
            into g
            orderby g.Key.Categoria
            select new { ID = g.Key.IdCategoria, CategoriaNome = g.Key.Categoria, TotalItem = g.Count() };
```

Isto itera sobre `List<n'>`:

```
foreach (var categ in lst)
{ ... }
```

E isto você tenta iterar sobre `n'` que não é "iterável":

```
foreach (var item in categ)
{ ... }
```

Portanto, o erro.

---

**EDIT**

Segundo seu comentário na outra resposta, você quer agrupar por categorias. Portanto, modifique sua sentença para:

```
var lst = from p in Produto.produtos
    join c in Produto.categorias
    on p.IdCategoria equals c.IdCategoria
    group p by new { c.IdCategoria, c.Categoria }
        into g
        orderby g.Key.Categoria;
```

O primeiro `foreach` fica assim:

```
foreach (var categ in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Categoria: {1}, Total Item: {2}", categ.Key.IdCategoria, categ.Key.Categoria, categ.Count());
    ...
```

O segundo fica igual:

```
foreach (var item in categ)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t\tID: {0}, Produto: {1}", item.IdProduto, item.Produto);
}
```

Comment: Esse código nao envolve `dynamic` de todo. O resultado da primeira query é uma `List<n'>`, em que `n'` é um tipo anonimo.

Comment: Normalmente quando vejo questões sobre tipos anônimos, vejo a turma usando `dynamic`. Obrigado pela sugestão. Já alterei.

Comment: De nada :) Na verdade, as duas coisas são bem distintas. Com tipos anónimos, mantemos *static typing*, ou seja, só podemos aceder a propriedades/métodos que realmente existam. Se tentarmos um acesso inválido, o compilador não vai deixar fazer build, ex: `var a = new { str = "uma string" }; a.propriedadeInvalida;`

Comment: Com `dynamic`, todos os acessos a essa variável vão ser compilados dinamicamente *quando o programa for corrido*. Ou seja, se houver algum erro no código, so vamos saber quando a excepção for lançada. O código pode ter 15 erros, mas vai compilar na mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos mudar tudo.

```
var lstCategorias = (from p in Produto.categorias select p).ToList();
foreach (var categoria in lstCategorias)
{
     var lstProdutos = (from p in Produto.produtos where p.IdCategoria=categoria.ID select p).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Categoria: {1}, Total Item: {2}", categoria.ID, categoria.CategoriaNome, lstProdutos.Count);
    foreach (var item in lstProdutos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tID: {0}, Produto: {1}", item.IdProduto, item.Produto); <b>// Linha com o Erro</b>
    }
}
```

Explicando:

Obtendo as categorias

```
var lstCategorias = (from p in Produto.categorias select p).ToList();
```

Iterando com foreach

```
foreach (var categoria in lstCategorias)
```

Filtrando os Produtos da categoria dentro do foreach

```
var lstProdutos = (from p in Produto.produtos where p.IdCategoria=categoria.ID select p).ToList();
```

Imprimindo o resultado

```
Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Categoria: {1}, Total Item: {2}", categoria.ID, 
categoria.CategoriaNome, lstProdutos.Count);
```

Novo foreach para listar os produtos da categoria

```
foreach (var item in lstProdutos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t\tID: {0}, Produto: {1}", item.IdProduto, item.Produto); <b>// Linha com o Erro</b>
```

Comment: O ideal é você explicar sua resposta, para entendermos melhor.

Comment: Cigano, não deu certo. Ele dá erro com a mesma mensagem só que agora no segundo Foreach:<code>    foreach (var item in categ)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tID: {0}, Produto: {1}", item.IdProduto, item.Produto); <b>// Linha com o Erro</b>
    }</code>

Comment: @KellySoares Esta resposta não é minha. Aliás, não sei qual o seu objetivo. Seria legal você editar sua resposta e explicar o objetivo pra que eu possa melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Eu quero listar os grupos de categoria no primeiro FOREACH e no segundo quero listar os produtos que fazem parte deste grupo.

Comment: Tá dificil hein brothen...

Comment: Vou fazer outro tópico com uma estrutura aproximada.